# what is the default size of jvm heap when using maven to create jvm?

Tags: centos, vps, memory, java, maven

I am using the server started by the following command.

```
mvn jetty:run
```

i want to stop the server, but i failed to run mvn jetty:stop, even faild to run java -version, why?

```
[mirror@home wpse]$ mvn jetty:stop              /////////////
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
[mirror@home wpse]$ java                     //////////////
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
[mirror@home wpse]$ java -version             ///////////////
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

the fact is i still have about 50M of free memory, why i failed to run java -version? how much memory do java -version command need?

```
Mem:   1048800k total,   993728k used,    55072k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached
```

the question is what is the default size of jvm heap when using maven to create jvm?

how to make java use a smaller heap when using maven?